# Solving L1-Minimization problem with [R]NN

Tags: neural-networks, optimization

I want to solve $$ \min \:\: \vert \vert x \vert \vert_1 \:\:\:\: s.t. \:\: Ax=y $$
using a Neural Network or Recurrent Neural Network.

I found only [this paper](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~btennis/Neural%20Nets/), but there $x$ has to be greater or equal zero.
Do you know any other good papers, tutorials or other projects about how to solve this problem using a network?

Comment: This may not be the best way, but if you substitute $x1 - x2$ for $x$, where $x1$ and $x2$ are constrained to be non-negative, then you get a problem equivalent to your original, and involving only variables which are constrained to be non-negative. In particular, $x$ is now unconstrained.

Comment: It seems to me that $\mathbf x \ge \mathbf 0$ is no restriction at all, because you may add a suitably large constant to every $x_i$, adjust $\mathbf y$ accordingly, and there will be a solution with non-negative $\mathbf x$. One way to find such a constant is to find a single feasible vector $\mathbf x^{*}$: use $||\mathbf{x}^{*}||$ for the constant. (cc @MarkL.Stone)

Comment: @whuber There's more than one way to skin a cat. In any event, a neural network is certainly not the most computationally efficient or robust way of solving a Linear Programming problem. So hopefully this whole exercise is just "for fun".

Comment: @Mark L.Stone: Do you know any other ways to solve this problem?
Why do you think this it is not comp. efficient or robust if I still reproduce the algorithm of a common solver?

Comment: Use software designed for Linear Programming, which implements a Simplex or Interior Point solver. You can not just pick up a book, any book, and hope to reproduce anything anywhere near that quality or robustness.  BTW, if your problem has special structure, such as network structure, that can be exploited to increase the efficiency.

Comment: @Mark L. Stone: Sorry, but I cannot comment due to my reputation. Which solvers do you think should work best when implemented as (R)NN?

Comment: @N8_Coder My point is that if you really want to solve a Linear programming problem, use software designed for it - don't use a neural network except for educational and experimental purposes.

Comment: @Mark L. Stone: It is for research purposes, so it would be interesting to know for me.

Comment: @N8_Coder You would be able to comment if you [*merge* your accounts](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so that the system understood you were the asker rather than some random person. Do NOT post comments as answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a recurrent neural network which solves the lasso problem. Here is the link to this paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.03443.pdf

I am also curious to know in what applications you need a neural network for the lasso problem.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you expand on your answer by briefly explaining the solution (if possible), and by providing a full citation (links tend to go dead)?

Comment: Sure! In the paper, the lasso problem is firstly converted to a smooth equivalent minimization with some constraints. Then, a neural network is proposed to the smooth problem, which indeed solves the lasso problem. More details are in the paper and it is not lengthy at all